# handleChange is not a function , react

Tags: reactjs, function, callback

I am trying to pass a function to a react component but it say that it is not a function. I can console log the props and I have set it up, as far as i can tell, the same  way I have always done. Please help, thanks!

EDIT: I get the same error when i try to test the onSubmit function, too

```
<div className="bookshelf">
        <Searchbar
          handleChange={onChange}
          addInputClass={"searchbar_mobile_input"}
          addBtnClass={"searchbar_mobile_btn"}
        />
        <div className="bookshelf_heading_container">
          <h2 className="bookshelf__heading">
            Release the Kraken of Knowledge!
          </h2>
        </div>
```

```
import React, {Fragment} from "react";
const SearchBar = ({ addBtnClass, addInputClass, handleChange }) => {
  console.log(handleChange)
  return (
    <Fragment>
        <form className="search__form__input" onSubmit={() => handleSubmit(e)}>
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Search by Title/Author"
        className={`searchbar__input ${addInputClass}`}
        name="search"
        onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
      ></input>
      <button type="submit" className={`btn ${addBtnClass}`}>
        Search
      </button>
    </form>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: Where are you defining your `onChange` function? Also, `handleSubmit` isn't defined anywhere. Nor is the `e` you're passing in as the argument

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-dew-v1gjd?file=/src/App.js:0-661) that should help you. You should be able to take this simplified example and work out how to apply it to your example. I would've used your code but it was incomplete and no sandbox was provided.

```
import React from "react";

export default function AppLogic() {
  const [readValue, writeValue] = React.useState("");
  const handleChange = (e) => writeValue(e.target.value);
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("Submitted");
  };
  const props = { readValue, handleChange, handleSubmit };
  return <AppView {...props} />;
}

function AppView({ handleSubmit, handleChange, readValue }) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Name</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input onChange={handleChange} value={readValue} />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
      <p>{readValue}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```